# Incorrect space in cleartool trigger name prevent me from removing it

Tags: triggers, clearcase

I have created a ClearCase trigger on my VOB, which I have put space by mistake at the beginning of its name.
Now I can't remove it, or get its description since "space" is not allowed in the other command:

1) Here is how I can see it:

```
cleartool lstype -kind trtype -invob /vobs/xx/yy/
*--11-06T14:43  tttttt     trigger type " VER_CI_TRIGGER"*
```

2) while trying to remove it or get its description:

```
cleartool describe trtype:VER_CI_TRIGGER@vob:/vobs/xx/yy
*cleartool: Error: Trigger type not found: "VER_CI_TRIGGER".*

cleartool describe trtype:' VER_CI_TRIGGER'@vob:/vobs/xx/yy
cleartool: Error: Trigger type not found: " VER_CI_TRIGGER".
```

How can I get around that?

Answer (score 0):

Try and use the [`cleartool rmtype`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmtype.htm) first

```
cleartool rmtype trtype:" VER_CI_TRIGGER@vob:/vobs/xx"
or
cleartool rmtype "trtype: VER_CI_TRIGGER@vob:/vobs/xx"
```

Alternatively, as noted by [the OP Ahmed Shaboon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7760955/ahmed-shaboon) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58742863/incorrect-space-in-cleartool-trigger-name-prevent-me-from-removing-it/58742986#comment103775254_58742986):

```
cleartool rmtype -rmall "trtype: VER_CI_TRIGGER"
```

That will remove it from all the vobs.

Comment: Both are giving me cleartool: Error: Trigger type not found: " VER_CI_TRIGGER".

Comment: I replaced the CT with cleartool and re-used your second command with -rmall, it worked. Thanks

Comment: @AhmedShaboon Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try using cleartool lstype -kind trtype -fmt "%dn\t%n\n" to get the dbid, then do cleartool rmtype dbid:(number from last command)